# Why is my field not showing up in the template?

Tags: theming

I created a new field of the type [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) for the Basic page content type and the field name is field_secondary_links.

All the pages on the site operate based on custom templates and I edited node--page.tpl.php in order to show the links on the page. I added this:

```
<div id="secondary-links"><?php print render($content['field_secondary_links']); ?></div>
```

The div appears in the HTML structure, but it turns out empty, even though I know for sure the fields aren't empty. What am I doing wrong?

Using print_r($node), I found out the field is indeed there:

```
[field_secondary_links] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => http://www.google.com
                            [title] => Link 1
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [html] => 1
                            [query] => 
                            [fragment] => 
                            [absolute] => 1
                            [display_url] => http://www.google.com
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => http://ww.google.com
                            [title] => Link 2
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [html] => 1
                            [query] => 
                            [fragment] => 
                            [absolute] => 1
                            [display_url] => http://ww.google.com
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => http://www.google.com
                            [title] => Link 3
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [html] => 1
                            [query] => 
                            [fragment] => 
                            [absolute] => 1
                            [display_url] => http://www.google.com
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right. If field_secondary_links is in $content, it should be rendering it out. You might want to double check that the field is named correctly. If you have [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed, try using `dpm($content)` to make sure the field is in there, that it is named right, and the the correct data is getting pulled in.

EDIT =======================================================
If $content is unavalible for whatever reason, you can still render this from $node, but it's a bit diffrent. Your code should look like this:

```
<div id="secondary-links"><?php  print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_secondary_links', array('label'=>'hidden'))); ?></div>
```

You can remove the `array('label'=>'hidden')` from field_view_field() if you want the label to show up.

That should prerender and then render the field for you. Not sure why your $content is missing though, but this should be a workable work-around.

Comment: I checked multiple times. Will try with devel now. By the way, can I also do print_r() here?

Comment: Using print_r($node) I found out it is there, will post it in my answer now.

Comment: Is it also in $content? You used print_r on $node, which is different from $content.

Comment: well, print_r($content) is not rendering anything, I just get an empty <pre></pre>, is this a good hint?

Comment: Yeah, if your $content is blank, that's gonna be your issue. There is a way you can render out the content from node, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: This worked! I am not the original developer, so I wouldn't know. Just out of curiosity, what could be a possible reason?

Comment: Not 100% sure why, but my first guess would be it's getting over-ridden in ether your template.php file, or in a module somewhere. It's probably something you would have to dig for.

Comment: Another question: since I need a conditional (display only where !empty), how would you suggest I write it, since <?php if($content['field_secondary_links']): ?> etc. obviously won't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23067/discussion-between-jana-ristic-and-jance).